# Can this be patched?

Tags: tires, tire-pressure

[image]

I was going this morning to run some errors and saw that my car PSI was at zero. Went to the gas station to pump some air and once I left the tires was slowly decreasing in pressure. Can this incision be patched up? I don't think its as bad as it looks. I'm going to the tire shop tomorrow but want to see what you guys think? Thanks.

Comment: Is that where the air is coming from?  Did you test with soapy water or is it obvious enough to feel?  I just ask because I've seen nicks like that on the sidewall; that never leaked air.

Answer (score 6):

Expect to be told that damage that severe is not able to be safely repaired. It's not able to be unsafely repaired either. It's time for a replacement tire.

Sidewall damage, unless cosmetic, is always fatal. You may find a couple of posts here for small gouges in the heavier portion of the rubber. The key for those is "small" and "gouges," not rather large slices all the way through as in your tire.

Answer (score 4):

If a shop says we can fix it - leave - that damage has affected the plies used in the construction of the sidewall and it will fail even if they can get it to hold air.

I had a sharp stone do this to a new winter tyre.... Replacement - ah well its only money - but the only thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

That is not repairable damage; neither is a bald tire worth repairing.  If that were my tire, I'd be first asking who shoved a knife in it.

Comment: Now that you mention, it does look a lot like knife damage.

Comment: After I said that, I looked back at the picture.  It could be a lot of things, but that tire is in bad shape.  The sidewall is cracking, and you can tell by the tapered wear on the sidewall text that it's been run underinflated for a considerable distance.  It's entirely possible that they got something shoved into the sidewall by running it half-flat.

Answer (score 0):

Even if could be repaired. Is it worth the effort? Your tire is bald to the point of actually almost having no tread at all. This could present a safety issue such hydroplaning during a rain storm causing you to lose control and destroying your more expensive vehicle and injuring both driver and passengers.

If you weigh all the vehicle repair costs,higher insurance premiums, highway code violations and the fines and demerit points against the cost of 4 brand new tires....The latter is subsequently much cheaper in the long run with added benefit of enhanced safety which is priceless.